# I can't send email CakePHP

Tags: php, email, cakephp

It was testing my application in which you create a webservice with cakephp. At the time of testing and to debug my application I always kept my core value to 2. All worked for me and it was time to try all the core 0, everything worked except send email. But by changing the core 2 if it is sent and not understand why.

```
        $this->Email->to(array('username' => $responsable['User']['email']));
        $this->Email->subject = "Nuevo View";
        $this->Email->from = 'example@example.com';
        $this->Email->template = 'view_notification';
        $this->Email->layout = 'default';
        $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
        $result = $this->Email->send();
```

Comment: Are you sure that if debug mod 2  then email send otherwise not?

Comment: Very sure, changing the core sends the mail immediately. The worst is that I can not find any error or something that tells me it can be. @anantkumarsingh

Comment: I don't know why this staring behaviour, but may be i gave you one tricky solution. wait

Comment: @anantkumarsingh that solution? I find no solution yet

Comment: Given below. please check  and tell it's working or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the best solution, but it will work definitively for you. I suppose that your function is `sendMail()` through which you are sending mail.Try to do like below:-

```
public function sendMail(){

Configure::write('debug', 2); // just on debug mode specially for this function

$this->Email->to(array('username' => $responsable['User']['email']));
        $this->Email->subject = "Nuevo View";
        $this->Email->from = 'example@example.com';
        $this->Email->template = 'view_notification';
        $this->Email->layout = 'default';
        $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
        $result = $this->Email->send();

}
```

Note:- it's a sample because i don't know your function name and what other things you have in that function. just put that `debug mod line` at the very first line inside your function and job will done.

Comment: The strangest thing is that there is no error, apparently does not affect the Configure :: write ('debug'2) so I can not see the logs.

Comment: `Configure :: write ('debug',2)` you missed `,`

Comment: This error gives me to put the Configure::write('debug',2) Warning: file_put_contents(/home/nhernandez/public_html/view-app/web/app/tmp/logs/error.log) [http://php.net/function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/nhernandez/public_html/view-app/web/lib/Cake/Log/Engine/FileLog.php on line 142

Comment: off the mode in config file, clear the cache, put that line in your controller and then try.

Comment: Actually works, what concerns me first is the solution and second, many of other features that I have not work well with the debug on 2, try, after sending the email to change the debug to 0 but I can not function well my other functions .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79700/discussion-between-anant-kumar-singh-and-sioesi).

Comment: can we discuss it in chat?